# How to open iOS gallery app from React Native app

Tags: ios, react-native, deep-linking, react-native-ios, camera-roll

I'm having trouble opening iOS gallery app from React Native app.
I have the file url and asset url. I got the asset url from CameraRoll. Now I want to open the gallery itself to see the image.

This is the code that I use

```
openGallery = () => {
// this code is working on android using asset url
// sample url on iOS
// file url : file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A41FFC2E-06D4-445D-9B94-D21E885930C7/Documents/video/popcam-1527202811.mov
// asset url : assets-library://asset/asset.mov?id=D4C62335-EDB1-4A75-B94D-61C3D48CADEA&ext=mov
const { galleryUrl, source } = this.props
const url = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? source : galleryUrl
Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(canOpen => {
  if (canOpen) {
    Linking.openURL(url)
  } else {
    Alert.alert('Info', 'Under Development')
  }
})
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use cameraroll .. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html

Comment: I already use camera roll to get the asset url. 

I got this url (asset url : assets-library://asset/asset.mov?id=D4C62335-EDB1-4A75-B94D-61C3D48CADEA&ext=mov) from camera roll.

Camera roll only used to get the assets url, not opening the gallery itself

Comment: you can use react-native-image-picker

Answer (score 12):

```
openPhotos = () =>{
switch(Platform.OS){
  case "ios":
    Linking.openURL("photos-redirect://");
  break;
  case "android":
    Linking.openURL("content://media/internal/images/media");
  break;
  default:
    console.log("Could not open gallery app");
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Im unaware of a way to open a specific asset. However, you can open the Photos app with the following scheme:

`Linking.openURL('photos-redirect://')`